# Photos app - import into specific folder

Tags: photos.app, import

When I import a folder of photos into the Photos app there is an option at the top of the import window that says "Import to:" and there is an option Library where there is a dropdown of your existing folder hierarchy, but try as I might I can't get it to import into a specific folder. It always imports into My Albums root and I have to drag it to the correct location. I'm wondering what that function is supposed to do as it doesn't seem to do what I expect (or anything for that matter).

Answer (score 1):

Ok after about an hour fiddling around...

Import to Library is expecting an Album as the landing point. Nowhere is this documented and the word 'Library' is a bit confusing. If you point to an Album then it won't retain any folder structure and just dump all the images on the one Album. To maintain folder structure (which is grayed out with this option) just tick Library and let it go to root. Then drag that folder structure to its new location in the Folder hierarchy and everything works.